# How to find a result and apply localization in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Given the following sample data

```
db.cars.insertMany([
    {
        "category": "sedan",
        "model": {
            "manufacturer": {
                "en": "Mercedes",
                "ru": "Мерседес"
            },
            "number": "E320"
        }
    },
    {
        "category": "SUV",
        "model": {
            "manufacturer": {
                "en": "Audi",
                "ru": "Ауди"
            },
            "number": "Q7"
        }
    },

])
```

I can select a category by its' name with the following query

```
db.cars.find({'category': 'sedan'})
```

And also, if I want to do mapping for a given field, I can do the following

```
db.cars.aggregate({$project: {'model.manufacturer': '$model.manufacturer.ru'}})
```

Now combining those 2, I get

```
 db.cars.aggregate([{$match: {'category': 'SUV'}}, {$project: {'model.manufacturer': '$model.manufacturer.ru'}}])
```

Now my question is, is this a right approach, and if yes, how do I keep all the other values without typing them in the aggregation query(like `{'model': 1, ... }`)

Comment: change `$project` to `$addFields`

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks. Post this as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Adds new fields to documents. [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) outputs documents that contain all existing fields from the input documents and newly added fields..
>
> The [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) stage is equivalent to a `$project` stage that **explicitly** specifies all existing fields in the input documents and adds the new fields.
>
> Starting in version 4.2, MongoDB adds a new aggregation pipeline stage [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#pipe._S_set) that is an alias for [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/).

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/

```
db.cars.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "category": "SUV"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "model.manufacturer": "$model.manufacturer.ru"
    }
  }
])
```

or for MongoDB >= v4.2

```
db.cars.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "category": "SUV"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "model.manufacturer": "$model.manufacturer.ru"
    }
  }
])
```